# pandas get index for a row value

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with the following data frame

```
 like            max_interest    min_interest
 basketball       4               2
 football         2               0
 soccer           4               2
 softball         4               2
 volleyball       4               2
 swimming         2               0
 cheerleading     4               2
 baseball         4               2
```

I would like to group it by max_interest/min interest like

```
  group         max_interest                                                  min_interest
      4         basketball,soccer,softball,volleyball,cheerleading,baseball   N/A   
      2         football,swimming                                             basketball,soccre,softball,volleyball,cheerleading,baseball
      0         N/A                                                           football,swimming
```

I tried to make it work by using groupby(max_interest), but failed to find how to concatnate the like column

What this essentially does is concatnate row values of likes into string under heading of max_interest and similarly for mininterest.

There could be a way by writing handcoded logic of iterateng and keep appending the likes, but wish to know if I can write it using pandas/np library

help appreciated.

Comment: you should look at pivot_tables but I am not sure you can get a list of values into a single "cell" in one fell swoop

Comment: ok.will check on pivot table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split the  `DataFrame` and concatenate the appropriate likes according to interest level:

```
u = ({k: ','.join(n['like'])} for k, n in df.groupby('max_interest'))              
v = ({k: ','.join(n['like'])} for k, n in df.groupby('min_interest'))
```

Then create  a new `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(u)+list(v), index=['max_interest', 'max_interest', 'min_interest', 'min_interest']
```

Put the frame in the form you want it, use [groupby().last()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

```
adjustframe = df1.grouby(level=0).last().transpose()
```

Output:

```
                            max_interest                          min_interest                                                                      
0                                   NaN                             foot,swim                                                                      
2                             foot,swim  basket,soccer,soft,volley,cheer,base                                                                      
4  basket,soccer,soft,volley,cheer,base                                   NaN
```

To set the index name:

```
adjustframe.index.name = 'group'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option:

```
In [39]: def groupby(key):
   ....:         result = data.groupby(key).agg({'like': lambda v: ','.join(v)})
   ....:         result.index.name = 'group'
   ....:         result.columns = [key]
   ....:         return result
   ....:

In [40]: pd.concat((groupby(key) for key in ['max_interest', 'min_interest']), axis=1)
Out[40]:
                                            max_interest                                       min_interest
group
0                                                    NaN                                  football,swimming
2                                      football,swimming  basketball,soccer,softball,volleyball,cheerlea...
4      basketball,soccer,softball,volleyball,cheerlea...                                                NaN
```